# getFrame.SetBound is not working netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

getFrame().setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200) is not working in netbeans what would be the reason? i have also used getFrame().setTitle() and it is working but why not getFrame().setBounds(). i am stuck with it. I just want to know how to set the bounds of the frame view of the desktop application in netbeans. Please help Thnx.

Comment: Post some of your code here.

Comment: its the dektop application and i am setting its bounds using setbound (). so most of the code is ID generated

Comment: initComponents();
getFrame().setTitle("abc");
getFrame().setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);

Answer (score 1):

> so most of the code is ID generated

Right and somewhere in that code the setBounds() is being overridden by a pack() method probably. Which means you are executing your code at the wrong time. The simple solution is to let the FrameView do its job and don't use setBounds().

If you want full control over a frame and its components, then don't use an IDE to generate the code.